# Duplicate tags jquery-validation-plugin and jquery-validate

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

The [jquery-validate](/questions/tagged/jquery-validate) has 2,239 questions, [jquery-validation-plugin](/questions/tagged/jquery-validation-plugin) has 367.

Both refer to the same [jQuery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) by Jörn Zaefferer.

Comment: Possibly, `jquery-validation-engine` (18 questions) is another one.  Is there a mechanism in place at SO for reporting these other than coming to Meta?

Comment: @Sparky672: If you have enough vote in the tag, and enough rep, then you can suggest synonym. The enough vote part is quite a high hurdle, though, so meta is usually the place you will post such request.

Comment: So why, after a month, are all three tags still in use?  Reporting them on meta seems to be a broken way to do this.

Comment: [tag:jquery-validation-engine] is actually something different.

Comment: See also [jquery-validation-engine and validationengine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156456).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jquery-validation-plugin](/questions/tagged/jquery-validation-plugin) is a synonym.