# Duplicate tags validationengine and jquery-validation-engine

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

Same jQuery plugin: [validationengine](/questions/tagged/validationengine) [jquery-validation-engine](/questions/tagged/jquery-validation-engine). I would prefer the latter tag.

Please note [jquery-validate and jquery-validation-plugin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151645).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[validationengine](/questions/tagged/validationengine) is gone.